# setUp section in unit-tests seems to be ignored

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def SetUp(self):
        """ Setting up expected default values """
        self.test = RandomTest()

    def testReturnsArrayWithTuples(self):
        result = self.test.next()  # Error
        self.assert_(len(result), 5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I have a basic test, but it fails with this error message:

> AttributeError: 'MyTests' object has no attribute 'test'

Eclipse intellisense is showing me `self.test` though. What am I missing please?

Comment: I just found it. `SetUp(self):` has to be lowercase. `setUp(self):` So silly of me. Shall I delete the question, is it worth keeping it?

Comment: Posting an answer to your own question is totally fine and is even encouraged. So I would do that, as long as you don't mind having your "silly mistake" publicly documented ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, its quite embarrassing, as it was just a typo. :)

`def SetUp(self):` has to be lowercase `def setUp(self):` in order to be found and executed.

I hope it prevents someone else chasing ghosts like I did.